# Creating a custom framework Extension for sharepoint using vue js (vuespfx)

Tags: vue.js, sharepoint, yeoman, spfx, spfx-extension

Creating a custom extension framework for SharePoint online using the vuespfx, scaffold can't be generated?

> Using the Yeoman Generator with Vue: 
>   npm i -g generator-vuespfx, yo vuespfx

[image: creating scaffold using the yo vuespfx]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's may help full for you, to develop the client side extension component using react js
 [SharePoint Framework Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)

Answer (score 0):

You may choose [PnP/generator-SPFx](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/features/) which supports VUE framework( as I test the generator with vue framework, I didn't get erros).

[image]